# R Text Mining - Word Frequency in Corpus as Number of Documents that Contain the Word

Tags: r, text-mining

The **findFreqTerms()** command will tell me the high frequency words and how many times that they appear in the corpus.  However, what I am interested in is to know not how many times they appear in the corpus but rather how many documents contain the words.  For example, if I have a corpus of 10 documents and only one document contains the word "error", if the word "error" occurs 100 times in that one document, then **findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=100)** will return "error" (where dtm is my data term matrix).  Similarly, using **freqcy <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))**, I would find an associated frequency for "error" of 100.  However, what I want to be returned is an answer of 1 - I want to know that the word "error" only occurs in one document.

I have a one-off way to do it which I think could build code around to get what I want, but I have to think that there is already a solution for it.

Here is my current approach, using the "crude" dataset.

```
tdm<-DocumentTermMatrix(crude)
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(tdm))
freq[order(freq)]
```

This returns "oil" with a frequency of 80.

```
which(names(freq)=="oil")
```

This returns 782 and

```
inspect(tdm[,782])
```

gives

<>
Non-/sparse entries: 20/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 3
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

```
 Terms
```

Docs  oil

127   5

144  11

191   2

194   1

211   1

236   7

237   3

242   3

246   4

248   9

273   5

349   3

352   5

353   4

368   3

489   4

502   4

543   2

704   3

708   1

```
v<-as.vector(tdm[,782])
length(v[v>0])
```

Returns 20 - the number of documents that contain the word "oil".

I could create a code to loop over all elements in the tdm and store the length and then select the high frequencies.  I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you got

```
library(tm)
docs <- c(doc1="Foo bar bar bar", doc2="Lorem Foo Ipsum")
```

then you could e.g. do

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(docs)))
rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)>0)
# bar   foo ipsum lorem 
# 1     2     1     1
```

or

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(docs)), list(weighting=weightBin))
rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
# bar   foo ipsum lorem 
# 1     2     1     1
```

to get the number of documents, which contain each token.

Answer (score 0):

This is a measure called the *document frequency* of a term feature, which in its simplest form refers to the count of documents in which a term occurs.  It is an integral part of common feature weighting schemes such as [*tf-idf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Inverse_document_frequency_2) (when inverted and log-transformed).

The **quanteda** package for text analysis has this built-in, if you are looking for an efficient implementation that works with the sparse document-term matrix structures.  Example:

```
require(quanteda)
inaugCorpus
## Corpus consisting of 57 documents.
myDfm <- dfm(inaugCorpus, verbose = FALSE)
head(docfreq(myDfm))
## fellow-citizens              of             the          senate             and           house 
##              19              57              57               9              57               8 
docfreq(myDfm)["terror"]
## terror 
##      7
```